# How to assign builtin methods on console and document to variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to implement conditional assignment of the console.log() method to a variable as follows:

```
var dbglevel = 1;
var dbg = (dbglevel > 0) ? console.log : function(){};

dbg('message'); // throws TypeError
```

> TypeError: 'log' called on an object that does not implement interface
>   Console.

It used to work but something changed in Firefox 30. Now I have no idea if it was ever *supposed* to work. The reason I have my doubts is that I've seen the same thing with the **document** object. Compare the results of these two function assignments, the first is a function wrapper and the second is direct assignment to the method:

```
function qs1(q) { return document.querySelector(q); }; // wrapper
qs1('head'); // works

var qs2 = document.querySelector;
qs2('head'); // throws TypeError
```

> TypeError: 'querySelector' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface Document.

What am I seeing here? Why does direct assignment of the method to a variable break its "interface" to it's parent object?

My reason for wanting to do this is twofold:

1.) The assignment syntax is shorter and I don't need to worry about declaring arguments,
2.) More importantly, I want my dbg() calls to report the correct file and line number to the console. If the function is a wrapper the console always shows the line number of the console.log call in that wrapper. I don't want to emulate the line number logging because the normal method of calling `console.log` directly gives you a clickable link to view source centered on the line that called it.

I'm **not** looking for a workaround involving plugins like FireBug, pre-processing (LESS/SASS), or third-party scripts. The solution only needs to work on vanilla Firefox 30 or later and the specific problem I'm trying to solve is how to compress the following code on every line I want to conditionally log:

```
if (typeof cfg.DEBUG != 'undefined' && cfg.DEBUG > 2) console.log(something);
```

... to this ...

```
dbg(something);
```

... where the `dbg()` function does any appropriate conditional evaluation and then shows the same line number as if I had called console.log directly.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is a simple workaround:

```
var dbglevel = 1;
var dbg = (dbglevel > 0) ? function(msg){console.log(msg);} : function(){};

dbg('message'); // prints message
```

By the way, assigning a native function to a `var` throws `TypeError` in Chrome as well.
The problem is binding: when you are aliasing functions like you did, they are called on the global object, and instead you need to have them bound to `console` or `document` in turn.

So the right way to your aliasing is like:

```
var dbg = console.log.bind(console);
```

or

```
var qs2 = document.querySelector.bind(document);
```

Assuming you are running ES5 at least. So, if you need back compatibility, you'd probably want to use something like the workaround above (perhaps something more elaborate to take into account a variable number of arguments, using `apply` and the `arguments` object).

If you are sure you have access to ES5 features, use:

```
var dbglevel = 1;
var dbg = (dbglevel > 0) ? console.log.bind(console) : function(){};

dbg('message'); // prints message
```

Comment: The simple workaround doesn't solve the main issue. If put in a file called 'test.js' the code above will print `test.js:2` in the console. I need it to show `test.js:4`, ie. the line number of the calling statement not the line you defined `dbg` at.

Comment: Ah! The "right way" works. I never knew about bind. Thank you for the explanation of aliasing as well. I've used JS for 12 years and never needed to do anything like this before.

Comment: I can be sure of ES5, my project is targeting latest gecko/ff/webkit backends. No IE.

Comment: Great, back compatibility is more often than not a pain in the @$$ -_-
If you needed to be extra sure, you could even check if `Function.bind` exists, and if not, revert to the pre-ES5 workaround